# Displaying chars as ints without explicit cast

Tags: c++, casting, char, cout

Every time I send a char to the cout object, it displays in ASCII characters unless I cast it to an int.

**Q:** Is there a way to display the numerical value of a char without an explicit cast?

I read somewhere that doing too many casts in your code could lead to a loss of integrity (of your program). I am guessing that chars display in ASCII for a particular reason, but I'm not sure why.

I am essentially creating a game. I am using small numbers (unsigned chars) that I plan to display to the console. I may be paranoid, but I get this uneasy feeling whenever I spam `static_cast<int>` everywhere in my code.

Comment: Can't you just use `int` instead of `unsigned char`? You're not using chars it to save memory, aren't you?

Comment: The words you have read, "loss of integrity," are probably not precise enough for their present use.  It depends on what you use the casts for.  Bad casts are used to avoid the need to design and maintain a proper set of types, but this is not what you are doing here.  The effect of the stream-insertion operator `<<` is well-defined and broadly understood.  To convert `char` to `int` to feed it to a stream is standard technique.  There is no threat to integrity here.

Comment: @jrok Yea I am using unsigned chars to save memory. Should I not be doing that?

Comment: @Dasaru: if you've got several million, the memory savings add up. if you've got a few dozen, the extra code needed will swamp the data savnigs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with type-casting, though, especially if you use `static_cast` to do it.  That is what you should be using.  It allows the compiler to validate the type-cast and make sure it is safe.

To change the behavior of the `<<` operator, you would have to override the default `<<` operator for `char` values, eg:

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &os, char c)
{
    os << static_cast<int>(c);
    return os;
}

char c = ...;
std::cout << c;
```

You could create a custom type that takes a `char` as input and then implement the `<<` operator for that type, eg:

```
struct CharToInt
{
    int val;
    CharToInt(char c) : val(static_cast<int>(c)) {}
};

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &os, const CharToInt &c)
{
    os << c.val;
    return os;
}

char c = ...;
std::cout << CharToInt(c);
```

You could create a function that does something similar, then you don't have to override the `<<` operator, eg:

```
int CharToInt(char c)
{
    return c;
}

char c = ...;
std::cout << CharToInt(c);
```

Comment: Replacing the default streaming operator is not generally a good idea... you might want to print numbers for now, but may want to print characters as characters somewhere later in your code.  Separately, the correct return type for `operator<<` is `std::ostream&` (i.e. it should be a reference).

Comment: That's why I provided alternatives that are more explicit. And I updated my examples, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As things go, this is a reasonable use of casts, but yes it can be improved.  The "loss of integrity" involved is simply that if one of the data types changes from char to say double the cast will continue to compile but probably not do what you want.  You can create a helper function instead:

```
inline int to_int(char c) { return static_cast<int>(c); }
```

Unlike the static_cast, this will only kick in when the original type is `char`, so if you changed to something like `double` you'd get a compiler warning - effectively a reminder to review your code.

Comment: He has asked how to do it without CASTs.  Although (and I haven't been doing a TON of C++ lately) I really like this. :-)

Comment: I think you can also do something like `template <typename T, typename U> T implicit_conversion(const U &u) { return u; }`. Use like `std::cout << implicit_conversion<int>(c);` (untested, I can't remember which order the template arguments should be in for the deduction to work). That works for all types without containing any casts, so the compiler gets the opportunity to warn you if your conversion is legal but suspect.

Comment: @trumpetlicks: "doing too many casts in your code"... this is called factoring... doing something potentially ugly in one controlled place.

Comment: @Steve: in the above code you can omit the static_cast<int>() if you don't feel it's adding value as documentation and simply let the return promote the char to int....

Comment: @Tony: agreed, the idea of my function is that when "you change to something like `double`", you get a warning only if your compiler thinks that converting the new type to `int` warrants one. So for example you can change to `short` without updating the code, because the `short -> int` conversion is no more worrying than `char -> int`.

Comment: Come to think of it, if I didn't want the `static_cast` and didn't want to write a template, I think I'd put the implicit conversion in the calling code rather than the function: `int to_int(int i) { return i; }`. Saves writing a bunch of overloads.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: the aim seems very specifically to display the ASCII codes of characters - `int` isn't itself significant as `short` or `long` would work as well.  On that basis, `int to_ascii_num(char)` might be a better name, but I don't see any reason to loosen the parameter type.